# How to test HTML5 Audio recording on chrome 48

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, getusermedia

I'm pretty aware of this warning that being shown when attempting to ask permission of using the Mic on non HTTPS origins using chrome.

> getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details.

So my question is there a way to test, demo, sandbox, etc this feature of HTML5 in chrome without having to buy/install/configure or create a ssl certificate ?

I read something on SO about `localhost` being treated as a secure origin over http (just tested this with chrome 48 and it's not working).

Is there a way to use IP's (e.g : 192.168.1.2) instead of example.com when using this chrome flag  ?

> --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="example.com"